# Passing a variable in getElementbyID()

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is it possible to pass javascript variable in getElementbyId()??

This is my radio code:

```
echo '<td><input id="dis1" type="radio" name="select" value="1" /></td>';
echo '<td>'.$poke[0]."<br>";
echo 'Level:'.$level[0]."<br>";
echo 'Health:'.$health[0]."<br></td>";
```

The below is my javascript code...in which first the id value is stored in PHP cvariable and then stored in javascript and using this javascript variable, I will disable the radio button. !

```
<script>
var dis_value = <?php echo $dis_value; ?>;                          //$dis_value = dis1
document.getElementById("dis_value").disabled=true;
</script>
```

But dunno why it seems not to be working?? are there any constraints which I need to follow if I am using a variable in getElementbyID ???

Comment: Nopes..it doesnt work either! :\

Comment: `"dis_value"` is a string. `dis_value` (notice the lack of quotes) is a variable.

Answer (score 2):

**First**, if you are generating JavaScript with PHP, then you need to generate real JavaScript. You can't just dump a variable into the script.

As it stands, your generated JavaScript is going to look like:

```
var dis_value = dis1;
```

which will throw a reference error since `dis1` is not defined.

Convert the contents of your PHP string into a JavaScript string:

```
var dis_value = <?php echo json_encode($dis_value); ?>
```

**Second**, if you want to use a variable, then use a variable, not a string literal.

Remove the quotes.

```
document.getElementById(dis_value) …
```

---

That said, why are you bothering to involve JavaScript in this in the first place?

```
<td><input id="dis1" type="radio" name="select" value="1" <?php
    if ($dis_value == "dis1") {
        echo "disabled";
    }
?>/></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to remove quotes from var

```
 <script>
var dis_value = "<?php echo $dis_value; ?>";                          //$dis_value = dis1
document.getElementById(dis_value).disabled=true;
</script>
```

Comment: Nopes..I am getting the value from php to javascript variable..!
But its not disabling it!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<script>
var dis_value = '<?php echo $dis_value; ?>'; 
document.getElementById(dis_value).disabled=true;
</script>
```